# How to make a custom Calender in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

So this is what my calender is supposed to look like;
[image]

I'm thinking of making a listView of days, but how do I make it linked to an actual calender so I get the correct days/dates ?

Answer (score 0):

Create the current week from any date using [weekday](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.0/dart-core/DateTime/weekday.html) something like this:

```dart
void main() {
  final any = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 2));

  final dateOnly = DateTime(any.year, any.month, any.day);
  final week = [
    for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) 
      dateOnly.subtract(Duration(days: dateOnly.weekday - i))
  ];
}
```